# Iterate over list of dictionaries efficiently in pagination

Tags: python, flask, pagination, jinja2

Flask pagination supports pagination directly over DB objects, whereas I need to paginate and render efficiently a huge list of records.

```
def modify(records):
    for rec in records:
        _rec = to_dict(rec, keys=['required', 'keys', 'only']) 
        _rec.update({'cal_vals': calculated_Vals(rec))
        yield _rec   

@app.route('/display/<type>/' methods=['POST'])
def render_records(typ):
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    records = db.objects.find(type=typ) #Huge list 30K to 40K records
    records = modify(records) 
    # This wont work as it takes out the count from db.objects.all()  
    records = records.paginate(page, per_page=200, False)
    return render_template(
    'show_records.html',
     response ={'records': records, 'context_vars':other_vals()},
```

What are the other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly. Are you actually experiencing performance issues? 40000 records is not a lot and can be handled easily by virtually any database.

Comment: Please update your question to state which database you're using and database library you're using to access it. These are important details.

Comment: What the record looks like, how they are ordered, and what `typ` actually does would help too.  Also why do you think splitting the result up into pages is a good idea? what does modify do?

Comment: @Soviut Can you please answer this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543343/manage-values-of-a-dictionary-in-different-pages-in-python-flask-application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've had to make a lot of assumptions because your question lacks a lot of detail about what database is being used and what database library.**

A database should have no trouble handling 40,000 records. Your performance issue is probably related to the fact that you're running your `modify()` function on every record, forcing the database library to "materialize" every record in memory at once. Only then are you running your pagination at which point you discard 99% of those results *after* you've spent a lot of time modifying them all.

The solution is to only run your function on the paginated results.

```
records = db.objects.find(type=typ)
paginated_records = records.paginate(page, per_page=200, False)
modified_records = modify(paginated_records) # this only runs on 200 records
```